# Public API giving me CORS when fetching with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access Datamuse API which is free up to some number of requests, according to their website.

This is an example endpoint:
https://api.datamuse.com/words?k=rza&arhy=1&max=30&sl=cabeza&v=es

But I'm getting CORS error using the fetch API, my code:

```
let response = await fetch(`https://api.datamuse.com/words?k=rza&arhy=1&max=30&sl=cabeza&v=es`);
let data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

Are you having a browser run the code? If that's the case, be noticed that your browser is blocking the response although you can see the response body in the network tab of the developer tools.

[image]

However, usually a client program that runs outside browser is used to access APIs.
For this purpose you can use available REST clients like [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) or [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or a command line tool like [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/).

HTH

### Update

A server-side code  will do the work too.

Comment: I was fetching it from a simple .js file, but I guess I have to use a server right? I tried using file_get_contents with php and it worked, so I think that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The .js file runs inside the browser, so the problem will be the same. Calling the API from a server program will do the work if you have a server.